# How would I translate “I slipped him a twenty” into German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

What’s a good translation of *slipped* in the following context?

> I slipped him a twenty.

Which means:

> I discreetly handed him twenty dollars

Comment: (OT: Your username makes no sense)

Comment: (OT: Your username is pretty funny :D)

Comment: @AntonSherwood Your observation is decidedly on topic.Or is your opposition derisively on toothpick? Or is the obfuscation deplorably atopical?

Comment: @Breeze I only got 1 hour of German back in high school, and that was 10 years ago. What does his username mean?

Comment: @Nzall I doesn't really mean anything. Literally it's "upsh.tted customer", but I have no idea what *up*sh.tting is supposed to be and how it can be done to/with a customer. (And even if this word has some slang meaning in English (maybe?), it doesn't mean anything in German)

Comment: @Nzall Goes along with the icon which shows the Chinese sign for 'customer'

Comment: It would mean "a customer opened by shitting", or "Open-shitted customer". What deviantfan refers to would be "Draufgeschissener Kunde".

Comment: The avatar probably means "Kunden: nein, danke", oder "Hier: Servicewüste"

Comment: @TheBlastOne About opened: Not a linguist, but can't it mean both? (Vielleicht scheint mein Dialekt durch...)

Comment: The name's meaning is supposed to be like, „Die Aktiengesellschaft scheißt auf ihre Kunden,” (“The corporation defecates _upon_ its customers”) like when I was talking with a couple of old ladies and one said something like, „Die Politiker scheißen auf uns!”  (One of _auf_'s many meanings is _upon_.)  The avatar represents customers/users being treated despicably.

Comment: That would be a Draufgeschissenwordener Kunde :-() (not a final truth, though)

Comment: @TheBlastOne Well, that's too long for a username.

Comment: But maybe I should register an email account with that name at http://www.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk.com/

Comment: @AufgeschissenerKunde: Kunden werden angeschissen -> Angeschissener Kunde.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I slipped him a twenty.

would probably be best translated as

> Ich habe ihm 'nen Zwanziger zugesteckt.

or

> Ich hab' ihm 'nen Zwanziger zugesteckt.

The shortening of "einen Zwanziger" to "'nen Zwanziger" adds to the casual tone. Additionally, one could shorten "ich habe" to "ich hab'".

Comment: Not a big fan of the *'nen*, but what do you think of *hab'* instead of *habe* to stay in the same tone?

Comment: @Thomas Nice idea. Shorting both is probably more true to life. I personally like "Ich habe ihm 'nen Zwanziger zugesteckt" better, because of its rhythm.

Comment: "Ich steckte ihm 'n Zwanziger zu". Für "Ich habe .." wäre "I have slipped him ..." das zu Übersetzende, oder?

Comment: Instead of “Zwanziger” people often colloquially say “Zwanni”. There's also “Fuffi” (Fünfziger) and “Hunni” (Hunderter). But there is nothing (I know of) for “Zehner” and the other bills.

Comment: @userunknown Technically you're right. I switched tempi from past tense to present perfect, because that version IMO sounds way more natural. In past tense, the sentence would be "Ich steckte ihm 'nen Zwanziger zu".

Comment: @PerlDuck You're correct. But in this case, I think, "Zwanni" would overdo the colloquial tone, compared to the English origin. To talk about a "Zwanni" here would probably equal referring to the president that's depicted on the respective dollar bill in English: "You can't go in here!" - "[Mister Franklin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_one_hundred-dollar_bill) says I can!" So, "Ich hab' ihm 'nen Zwanni zugesteckt" could be translated as something like "I introduced him to [President Jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_twenty-dollar_bill)".

Comment: For the record, "Zwanni" makes my toes curl. Never heard of in Austria, hopefully never will.

Comment: The line with "Zwanni" sounds like out of _Tatort _ when a detective bribes someone for information.

Comment: Note that the apostrophe in *hab'* is not conventional. You'd usually simply write *hab*.

Comment: Zwanni and also 'nen are only used in some regions of the german language area. Here in Austria you would say "an" (spoken with a stretched "a") for "einen".

Comment: 'Nen is horrible, I am listening with ostfriesischen ears :-)

Comment: "jmd etwas zustecken" hat für mich etwas sehr Formelles, beinahe "Aristokratisches" und gibt mAn den umgangssprachlichen Ton von "I slipped him a twenty" nicht so richtig wieder. "Rüberschieben" wie in der anderen Antwort dagegen schon.

Comment: I never heard Zwanni. But here we'd say Zwanzigerle (a twenty-let).

Answer (score 9):

Here (Hameln, close to Hannover) it would be, "Ich hab ihm 'n Zwanziger zugesteckt."

Back then in the days of the D-Mark we would have said, "Ich hab ihm 'ne Geige gegeben." That's because there used to be a violin (Geige) on the 20 DM bill.

Comment: +1 for Hannover, but I've never heard the _Geige_ part back then.

Comment: Me neither. Zwanni, ja, aber Geige?!?

Comment: [A violin?](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/20_DM_Serie4_Rueckseite.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Also somewhere between Hannover and Berlin, my take would be **"Ich schob ihm 'nen Zwanni rüber",** "Zwanni" being common slang for "Zwanziger", the casual word for "Zwanzig-Euro- (oder Mark-) Schein". I like the similarity in cadence and brevity of "twenty" and "Zwanni".

The image evoked by "rüberschieben", move/slide/push over, may be a table; not sure whether "slip" is exactly compatible. But chances are that the exact physical act in the phrase is coincidental anyway.

Comment: Bei "rüberschieben" fehlt meines Erachtens der Aspekt des unauffälligen, nachdem im OP gefragt wird.

Comment: @Burki Hm. Yes, it's not that explicit, true. I see, the OP's sentence could be used when discreetly tipping a bellhop in a hotel (no table involved, so the physical act has some importance).

Comment: Für mich ist "rüberschieben" das richtige. Hat für mich etwas unauffälliges, wenn auch nicht: geheimes.

Comment: To me the use of *Präteritum* here instead of *Perfekt* clashes violently with the otherwise coloquial tone. But that might be a regional thing.

Comment: @Emil or a context thing. If you tell your wife you have just tipped the bellhop it's perhaps past perfect; if you tell it as part of a story, it may be past tense like the rest of the story.